# Location Services iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, location

what is the best way to determine if two iPhone users are in the same radius of lets say 1000 meters.

What I am thinking is, both phones find out there location, then submit it to a central server. The problem is how would I figure out if they are within a certain distance of each other.

Comment: Hint: `distance = sqrt(Δx² + Δy² + Δz²)` (probably possible with SQL). You only need to convert the location coordinates (degrees) to meters, which is the difficult part (`(0, 0, 0)` would be north from Alaska at sea level, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) on the server to get a rough estimate on distances, and serve only the closest 4 or 5 to a the clients phone, then it can get a more accurate distance using the method `distanceFromLocation:` on CLLocation with just the few records sent by the server.